# ExpandableListView not showing up in my Activity

Tags: android, list, kotlin, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

**I am trying to implement an ExpandableListView in my app, but it's not showing up.**

I double checked:

1. The correct naming and referring-to all of my three XML layouts (for ExpandableListView, list header and list item),
2. Debugged to see if my lists are getting populated in `prepareListdata()` method (they are).

I think the **problem** is in my `ExpandableListAdapterClass`, as the
 class parameters `listDataHeader : ArrayList<String>, listDataChild : HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` are getting colored with a
squiggly grey line as not used.

**How to correctly tell my app that those are equal to my activity member variables?  Or is there something obvious I am missing?**

Here is my code:

Adapter

```
 class ExpandableListAdapter (context: Context, listDataHeader : ArrayList<String>, listDataChild : HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {


        var listDataHeader = arrayListOf<String>() //list sub-headers

        var listDataChild = HashMap<String, List<String>>() //list sub-points

        private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

        override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any {
            return this.listDataHeader[groupPosition]
        }

        override fun isChildSelectable(p0: Int, p1: Int): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
            val headerTitle: Int = getGroup(groupPosition) as Int
            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_group_header, parent, false)
            }

            val listHeader = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.list_header)
            listHeader?.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
            listHeader?.setText(headerTitle)

            return convertView
        }

        override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
            return this.listDataChild[this.listDataHeader[groupPosition]]!!.size
        }

        override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any {
            return this.listDataChild[this.listDataHeader[groupPosition]]!![childPosition]
        }

        override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
            return groupPosition.toLong()
        }

        override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
            val childText: Int = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as Int
            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item, parent, false)
            }

            val textListChild = convertView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.list_item)
            textListChild?.setText(childText)
            return convertView
        }

        override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
            return childPosition.toLong()
        }

        override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
            return this.listDataHeader.size
        }
    }
```

The rest of MainActivity and prepareListData() function

```
class MainListActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var adapter : ExpandableListAdapter
    val listDataHeader = arrayListOf<String>()
    val listDataChild = HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainlistactivity)
        prepareListData()
        adapter = ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild)
        expandable_list.setAdapter(adapter)
    }

    private fun prepareListData() {

        listDataHeader.add("Gathering data")
        listDataHeader.add("Simulate")

        val gatheringDataChildList = arrayListOf<String>()
        gatheringDataChildList.add("Record data: video + accelerometer")

        val simulateChildList = arrayListOf<String>()
        simulateChildList.add("Driving simulator")

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader[0], gatheringDataChildList)
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader[1], simulateChildList)
    }
```

Here's the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: So What You Exactly want to get populated ? colored item or something else? means your lsitview is empty in activity?

Comment: @AjayPandya yes. Neither my headers nor child items are showing. The view is completely empty.

Comment: @lidkxx is `expandable_list` a `RecyclerView`? If so, you need to specify `layoutManager` (most likely `LinearLayoutManager`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were were very close to solving the issue :)

```
 class ExpandableListAdapter (context: Context, listDataHeader : ArrayList<String>, listDataChild : HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {


        var listDataHeader = arrayListOf<String>() //list sub-headers

        var listDataChild = HashMap<String, List<String>>() //list sub-points
        //...
}
```

On the first line you specify constructor parameters, however you don't use them at all. (`var listDataHeader` is class' property, meaning that it's something different than constructor parameter `listDataHeader`)

You probably want something like this:

```
 class ExpandableListAdapter (context: Context, private val listDataHeader : ArrayList<String>, private val listDataChild : HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
//no declaration of another fields

//rest of adapter code here...
}
```

Please notice `private val` before constructor parameters. Those are class' properties declared directly within constructor. You can read more on them here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I think this is what I was looking for (can't tell 100% as I am getting some nasty library "/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so" not found, Sending SIG 9 error now, but this seems like another issue). A little documentation never killed nobody, I guess.